# Invalid session ID when using Page Object on nightwatch cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

**Update: Problem solved, check the comment**

I am trying to convert some frequently use test to page object and I have the following as **pg.js**:

```
 var myCommands ={
    security:function(username){
        this.click('@logon')
            .waitForElementVisible('@id',20000)
            .click('@id')
            .setValue('@id',username)
            .click('@device')
    },
    password:function(username){
        console.log(this)
        return this.useXpath()
                   .navigate()
                   .assert.elementPresent('@logon', 20000)
                   .click('@logon')
                   .waitForElementVisible('@id',20000)
                   .click('@id')
                   .setValue('@id',username)
                   .click('@password')
                   .waitForElementVisible('//input[@name="Answer"]', 20000);
    }
};

module.exports={
    url : 'https://mywebsite',
    commands :[myCommands], 
    elements:{

        logon:{
            locateStrategy: 'xpath',
            selector:'//a[@title="Log on"]'
        },
        id:{
            locateStrategy: 'xpath',
            selector:'//input[@name="userid"]'
        },
        device:{
            locateStrategy: 'xpath',
            selector:'//a[text() = "Login with PIN"]'
        },
        password:{
            locateStrategy: 'xpath',
            selector:'//a[text() = "Login with passwords"]'
        }
    }

};
```

From the console.log(this), I can see that the session ID and context is null :
[image]

And in my **test.js** ,I have this two lines:

```
var logon=client.page.pg()
 ....
 logon.password(username)
```

When I run the test, it shows

```
Error: Creating screenshot was not successful. Response was:
{ status: -1,
  value:
   { error: 'invalid session id',
     message: 'No active session with ID null',
     stacktrace: '' },
  errorStatus: 6,
  error: '' }
```

**My question is why the session is null? and if there is any problem how I set up the page object in either pg.js or test.js.**

Comment: Problem solved : after using page object in a test, you need to use Pageobject.api to call the functions, and cannot do client.whateveritis() . e.g.`logon.password(username).api.elements(blablabla) `

Comment: Could you please convert your comment into an answer and accept it. This way others can profit of your findings as well and we improve SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a nightwatch.conf.js file set up to show your page objects structure?

I am using nightwatch-cucumber with page object model and my structure is as follows:

```
//nightwatch.conf.js
const seleniumServer = require('selenium-server')
const phantomjs = require('phantomjs-prebuilt')
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver')

require('nightwatch-cucumber')({
  cucumberArgs: ['--require', 'hooks.js', '--require', 'features/step_definitions', '--format', 'pretty', '--format', 'json:reports/cucumber.json', 'features']
})

module.exports = {
  output_folder: 'reports',
  live_output: false,
  disable_colors: false,
  page_objects_path: 'pages',
  test_workers: false,
  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: seleniumServer.path,
    log_path: '',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444
  },
  test_settings: {
    default: {
      launch_url: 'whatevertheurlis.com',
      selenium_port: 4444,
      selenium_host: '127.0.0.1',
      globals: {
        base_url: 'baseurl.com'
      },
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      },
      selenium: {
        cli_args: {
          'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromedriver.path
        }
      },
      screenshots: {
        enabled : true,
        on_failure : true,
        path : 'screenshots/default'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the loginPage:

```
//pages/loginPage.js
module.exports = {
  url: function() {
    return this.api.globals.base_url + '/#/login';
  },

  elements: {
    body: 'body',
    error: 'div.error',
    header: '.header-title',
    emailInput: '#field_email',
    passwordInput: '#field_password',
    submitButton: '.btn-success'
  },

  commands: [{
    goTo: function() {
      return this.navigate()
                 .waitForElementVisible('@body', 3000);
    }
  }]
}
```

And this is the loginSteps:

```
//features/step_definitions/loginSteps.js
const { client } = require('nightwatch-cucumber')
const { defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber')

const loginPage = client.page.loginPage();
const navbar = client.page.navbar();
const resetPasswordPage = client.page.resetPasswordPage();
const shared = client.page.shared();

defineSupportCode(({ Given, Then, When }) => {
  Given(/^I go to login page$/, () => {
    return loginPage
      .goTo();
  })
})
```

We are using a slightly different method of doing this but hopefully this helps you see the layout of the tests.